# AutoCompleteBox for WP7 and AutoSelect!

Tags: windows-phone-7, autocompletebox

i would like to know how can disable in AutoCompleteBox for WP7 the autoselect when a word is equal with one of the itemsource.

Example:

```
ItemSource:
Test
Test 1
Test 2
Test 3
```

Now if i write "Test" autocompletebox automatically select the first item.. how can i disable this?

"AutoCompleteBox.IsTextCompletionEnabled = false" don't make what i want.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with set a variable "ListboxChecked = TRUE" on the event MouseLeftButtonDown of the listbox of autocompletebox and check on SelectionChanged if the variable is TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

That's how an autocomplete box works everywhere else. It will be confusing for users if it doesn't work like this.

Why are you using an AutoCompleteBox if you don't want this?

What would you want to happen if the user completely enters an item?

Comment: My problem is that if i write "Test" i cannot select "Test 1" because the autocompletebox select automatically "Test" and reset all, so i don't have the time for write " 1". I hope my problem is clear..

Comment: Here you can see a simple video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cyGhZI8wy1g in the first 15 seconds i try to write "Alessandro 2", but when the autocompletebox find "Alessandro" select it and reset all before i press the space..